# Oracle SELECT XMLELEMENT with Null

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g

Using Oracle 11, when I do

```
  SELECT XMLELEMENT("dummy", NULL) as xml_1 
    FROM dual
```

The output is `<dummy></dummy>`

How can I force to return  `<dummy />` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

is this just for presentation purposes, as both are the same. Oracle's function just happen to return non short tag style.

xmltype constructor though will convert it on 11g (in 10g the extract function did too, but not in 11g).

```
SQL> SELECT xmltype(XMLELEMENT("dummy", NULL).getclobval()) as xml_1 from dual;

XML_1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dummy/>
```